# How to select a particular div by chaining jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have 10 divs on a page and all the divs have same classes "hoverable", "contentDescription" and anchor tags within the divs. When I mouse hover on the anchor tags I want the image that is within the anchor tag to change. By using the below function though the image changes only for the hovered div, from firebug .net tab I could see all the divs trying to load the "orangeLock.gif". Any inputs on how to make only the currently hovered div to load a different icon making some minor changes using jQuery to the code below?

```
    <div onmouseout="hideHover()" onmouseover="showHover(this)" class="relContainer hoverable" style="width: 710px; height: 140px; opacity: 1; display: block; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <div class="thumbContainer"></div>
    <div class="contentDescription">
    <h2><a rel="doNothing" href="">Washington DC<img src="/images/lock.gif" name="a164a428047d96046a22db3373f057340"></a></h2></div>
    </div> 



function showHover(div){ 
       jQuery('.hoverable .contentDescription a').mouseover(function() {        
                   jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src', '/images/orangeLock.gif');
            }).mouseout(function(){
                 jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src', '/images/lock.gif');
            }); 

    }

![trying to load orangelock image][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function showHover(div){ 
   jQuery('.hoverable .contentDescription a').mouseover(function(ev) {        
               jQuery(ev.target).find('img').attr('src', '/images/orangeLock.gif');
        }).mouseout(function(ev){
             jQuery(ev.target).find('img').attr('src', '/images/lock.gif');
        }); 

}
```

Comment: oh no. It works but firebug still shows as if its trying to load the image.